# Where can I find a simple example of drawer and appbar used in docs site of Material UI v1?

Tags: material-ui

I want to add the same functionality the appbar and drawer has in the docs site i.e on mobile drawer is hidden and there's menu button on appbar but not on bigger screens. I'm not really able to find out anything by looking at the source in docs folder of material UI repo, Can anyone who has used material UI give a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the component Hidden, is really simple to use.
This example hide the paper at xs [breakpoint](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/layout/basics).

```
<Hidden xsDown>
    <Paper>Hidden on xs</Paper>
</Hidden>
```

Here, you have the [docs](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/layout/hidden) of Hidden.

Following the same functionallity, you can do something like this:

```
<Grid container gutter={0}>
    <Hidden xsDown><Grid item><Paper>Your side bar</Paper></Grid></Hidden>
    <Grid item xs>Your main component with the appBar</Grid>
</Grid>
```

So at breakpoint xs the side bar will hide